# Processing / C920 logitech capture frame rate video discourse

Tags: java, webcam, processing, frame-rate, logitech

I'm developing on Processing 2.0b, and i just bought a C920 logitech webam for a good capture quality.

Then I try to capture at `1920 x 1080`, the problem is that I'm under 15 fps per seconds..
When I list all the devices availsable to capture, the program write:

> Some size and fps
>
> ...
>
> -[61] "name=HD Pro Webcam C920,size=1024x576,fps=5"
>
> -[62] "name=HD Pro Webcam C920,size=1024x576,fps=30"
>
> -[63] "name=HD Pro Webcam C920,size=1280x720,fps=5"
>
> -[64] "name=HD Pro Webcam C920,size=1280x720,fps=30"
>
> -[65] "name=HD Pro Webcam C920,size=1600x896,fps=5"
>
> -[66] "name=HD Pro Webcam C920,size=1600x896,fps=30"
>
> -[67] "name=HD Pro Webcam C920,size=1920x1080,fps=5"
>
> -[68] "name=HD Pro Webcam C920,size=1920x1080,fps=30"
>
> ...
>
> some others size and fps...

So, as I can read.. for the size `1920 x 1080` the framerate of 30 fps is available..

What's wrong ??

Even if I force the program or run at 30 fps.. theres a crash pointing on `cam.start();` telling me that the framerate for this size isn't available...

Any help ... ?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem a few months back as well.  Here's what I found, searching through forums and contacting customer support:

The Logitech C920 only provides 30fps at 1080p with applications that supports H.264 directly, and can pull in the H.264 stream directly from the camera.  The C920 does on-board H.264 compression, but most applications don't support pulling the compressed stream straight from the camera; instead, they have to decompress then re-compress the stream, dropping the framerate.

Skype supports H.264 straight from the camera, so with Skype you should be able to get 1920x1080 @ 30fps, but you won't see this high framerate with Processing.  Also, I think you have to use Windows to use the Logitech drivers to support this.

I'll post the research I did a while back if I can find it, but unfortunately the answer is that you'll have to drop either your resolution or your framerate.

Comment: .. ok .. and what about a usb 3.0 capture from a video camera ? 
I mean card video acquistion ?
Can i have a good framerate with it ?

Comment: haven't tried that route, not sure.  if you find a route that works, please let us know.