# Webcam capture with directshow.net - performance

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net, webcam-capture

I have performance issues with capturing in DirectShow.NET. Using resolutions above 920x720 is resulting in stutters on my i5 dual core. The Logitech Software does record smooth on higher resolutions.

I use DirectShow.NET for capturing a webcam and muxing it in an AVI muxer with audio input. A File Writer writes it the capture to disk.

```
[Webcam (Logitech 920c)-> M-JPEG Compressor] + Microphone -> 
  -> Avi-Muxer -> File Writer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Webcam (Logitech 920c)-> MJPegCompressor
>
> The Logitech Software does record smooth on higher resolutions.

Logitech software is supposedly capturing MJPEG right from the camera, without software compression. It is not even about stock Windows M-JPEG compression being of substandard quality, the problem is USB 2.0 throughput: high resolution at high rates can only be captured hardware compressed.

You basically need either of the two or both:

1. Capture compressed video, M-JPEG or H.264, not raw
2. Look at Logitech software filter graph to find out exactly what topology they are using

See also:

- [Processing / C920 logitech capture frame rate video discourse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113560/processing-c920-logitech-capture-frame-rate-video-discourse/13116355#13116355)